# Recyclerview notifyItemMoved doesn't move items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'd like to preface this with saying that I am resetting the adapter because of animation that I'm doing with the rows when clearView is called. On the first pass, before I reset the adapter, notifyItemMoved works as expected with it switching views. Its only after I reset the adapter that the problem occurs.

That being said, after I reset the adapter with `setAdapter()` notifyItemMoved is called but it seems that the view gets..."stuck" when trying to move one position beyond its own. Putting logging in `onMove` in my ItemTouchHelper, revealed that it is getting called every second when trying to move to another position much like how `onChildDraw` is. Furthermore, logging showed that when the framework is calling `onMove(RecyclerView recyclerview, ViewHolder source, ViewHolder target)`
the source stays the same which makes sense. So for instance, if I'm trying to move from position 1 to 2 source will be 1 and target will be 2. BUT if I try to move further than that (let's say position 3), the view at position 1 will not move and source is stuck at 1 where it started and target is 3. This goes on till the end of the list.

Is there a reason resetting the adapter would cause notifyItemMoved not to work?

Here is an example of the code. I've removed names of Actual classes and methods to keep anonymity.

```
@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    ViewHolder previousViewHolder;
    ViewHolder nextViewHolder;
    int actualNextPosition =  (recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(viewHolder.itemView) + 1) - ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int actualPreviousPosition =  (recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(viewHolder.itemView) - 1) - ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if ((Math.abs(mScrolledAmount) / viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() * 100 >= 65)) {

        //We've reached the threshold for dropping a view into its rightful place
        if (mScrolledAmount < 0) {
            //we've dragged up and released
            if (recyclerView.getChildAt(actualPreviousPosition) != null) {
                previousViewHolder = ((ViewHolder) recyclerView
                        .getChildAt(actualPreviousPosition)
                        .getTag());

                TranslateAnimation currentViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, 0, -viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() + Math.abs(mScrolledAmount));
                currentViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
                viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(currentViewAnimator);

                TranslateAnimation previousViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, 0, viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() - Math.abs(previousViewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY()));
                previousViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
                previousViewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(previousViewAnimator);

                previousViewAnimator.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        LogUtil.d(TAG, "Current Translation" + viewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY() + "PREVIOUS" + previousViewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY());

                        ((Adapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).resetAdapterAndMakeCall(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), previousViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                        mViewHasMoved = false;
                        clearAfterAnimate(recyclerView, viewHolder, previousViewHolder);
                        mClearCallback.clearTouch();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            //we've dragged down and released
            if (recyclerView.getChildAt(actualNextPosition) != null) {
                nextViewHolder = ((ViewHolder) recyclerView
                        .getChildAt(actualNextPosition)
                        .getTag());

                //((Adapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).resetAdapterAndMakeCall(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), nextViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                TranslateAnimation currentViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, 0, viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() - mScrolledAmount);
                currentViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
                viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(currentViewAnimator);

                TranslateAnimation nextViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, 0, -viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() + Math.abs(nextViewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY()));
                nextViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
                nextViewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(nextViewAnimator);
                nextViewAnimator.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                        //LogUtil.d(TAG, "Current Translation" + viewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY() + "PREVIOUS" + nextViewHolder.itemView.getTranslationY());
                        ((Adapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).resetAdapterAndMakeCall(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), nextViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                        mViewHasMoved = false;
                        clearAfterAnimate(recyclerView, viewHolder, nextViewHolder);
                        mClearCallback.clearTouch();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }
                });
            }
            //Translate Animation positive translates up negative translates down
        }
    }
    else if ((Math.abs(mScrolledAmount) / viewHolder.itemView.getHeight() * 100 < 65)) {
        if (mScrolledAmount < 0) {
            //dragged up and released
            TranslateAnimation currentViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, mScrolledAmount, 0);
            currentViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
            currentViewAnimator.setFillAfter(true);
            viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(currentViewAnimator);
        }
        else {
            //dragged down and released
            TranslateAnimation currentViewAnimator = new TranslateAnimation(0,0, mScrolledAmount, 0);
            currentViewAnimator.setDuration(250);
            currentViewAnimator.setFillAfter(true);
            viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(currentViewAnimator);
        }
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);

        if (recyclerView.getChildAt(actualPreviousPosition) != null) {
            previousViewHolder = ((ViewHolder) recyclerView
                    .getChildAt(actualPreviousPosition)
                    .getTag());
            if (previousViewHolder.itemView != null) {
                super.clearView(recyclerView, previousViewHolder);
            }
        }

        if (recyclerView.getChildAt(actualNextPosition) != null) {
            nextViewHolder = ((ViewHolder) recyclerView
                    .getChildAt(actualNextPosition)
                    .getTag());
            if (nextViewHolder.itemView != null) {
                super.clearView(recyclerView, nextViewHolder);
            }
        }
    }

    LogUtil.d(TAG, "Cleared");

    viewHolder.itemView.setAlpha(ALPHA_FULL);

    if (viewHolder instanceof ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) {
        // Tell the view holder it's time to restore the idle state
        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
        // I have this if the user lifts their finger up and they've moved to another position or
        mHandler.postDelayed(() -> {
            if (mViewHasMoved) {
                mClearCallback.clearTouch();
                mViewHasMoved = false;
            }
        }, 250);
        itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder source, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    if (source.getItemViewType() != target.getItemViewType()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Notify the adapter of the move

    LogUtil.d(TAG, Integer.toString(source.getAdapterPosition()) + Integer.toString(target.getAdapterPosition()));
    mAdapter.onItemMove(source.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
    super.clearView(recyclerView, target);
    mViewHasMoved = true;
    return true;
}

//In a fragment
public void resetAdapterAndMakeCall(int fromPosition, int toPosition, List<Data> data) {
    LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerview.getLayoutManager();
    int firstItem = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    View firstItemView = manager.findViewByPosition(firstItem);
    float topOffset = firstItemView.getTop();
    mAdapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), data, this);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    manager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(firstItem, (int) topOffset);
}

@Override
public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    Collections.swap(list, fromPosition, toPosition);
    // The problem with doing a swap here for like order is that the adapter starts the position from 0
    // and we need to send the position to the server without a 0.
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    mViewHasMoved = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you share some code of how you are resetting the adapter, your recyclerview and ItemTouchHelper.

Comment: sure. Just added some.

Comment: in your mAdapter.onItemMove() (call contained inside onMove() method) do you call notifyItemMoved()? The document states that.

Comment: yes I do. I'll post that code too but it's pretty standard..

Comment: why are you calling     super.clearView(recyclerView, target);
  in your onMove() Method, it is generally been called when the interaction is over however in onMove the interaction will not be over.

Comment: because when I am moving my views, I apply translations to them which you aren't seeing because I didn't post my onChildDraw method. With those translations when onMove is called the translations still exist, so the view appears to actually go into a different position because it has an existing animation. Honestly, I didn't have to call super.clearView. I could've just set the translation back to 0 because that's essentially what super.clearView does along with resetting a view's elevation. But since I'm only resetting a view I'm moving to, it doesn't have any elevation.

Comment: well as per my understanding resetting the adapter shouldn't cause any problems but i am not sure what is leading to this problem.

Comment: haha yeah. I wouldn't think so either but this is the situation I'm in. Could possibly be a bug with ItemTouchHelper since it's so new. My other option is to call notifyDataSetChanged(); but that causes the screen to flicker ever so slightly and I can't have that :/
Rock -> me <- hard place

Comment: hey were you able to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up just snapping the view into it's rightful place with notifyDataSetChanged and changing the adapter's data.